# Change screen from an item of FlatList to that item's question screen

Tags: react-native

I'm having a English App in react native. I created a homepage with category and child_category like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67HW7.png). When I click on a category, it will show up a child_category of it. I did it well. But now I try to click on a child_category, it will change to a question screen like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX81k.png). I try to use OnPress but it's not working. Any Solution? This is my code.

**Here is the Navigator.js**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Start"
          component={Start}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'Homepage',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center', // căn giữa stack navigator header
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{
            title: 'Đăng nhập',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Signup"
          component={Signup}
          options={{
            title: 'Đăng ký',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ChangePass"
          component={ChangePass}
          options={{
            title: 'Cập nhật mật khẩu',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="EditProfile"
          component={EditProfile}
          options={{
            title: 'Cập nhật thông tin tài khoản',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={TabSrceen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'Welcome to MyEnglish',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              alignSelf: 'center',
            },
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="ChildCategoryItem"
          component={ChildCategoryItem}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              alignSelf: 'center',
            },
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Quiz"
          component={Quiz}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              alignSelf: 'center',
            },
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator;
```

**This is my Home.js. I use ChildCategory.js in this**

```
const Home = () => {
  //render chủ đề con
  const renderChildCategoryItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <ChildCaterogyItem
        // CategoryName={data.find((x) => x.id == idSelected)}
        data_child={item}
      />
    );
  };

  //render chủ đề chính
  const renderCategoryItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <CategoryItem
        onSelected={onSelected}
        selected={item.id == idSelected}
        {...item}
        data={item}
      />
    );
  };

  const [data_child, setData_child] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [idSelected, setIdSelected] = useState(1);

  const onSelected = (id) => {
    setIdSelected(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _fetchAllCategory();
    _fetchListChildCategory();
  }, [idSelected]);

  //fetch data chủ đề
  const _fetchAllCategory = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/api/category', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.status == 200) {
        setData(data.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  //fetch data chủ đề con
  const _fetchListChildCategory = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch(
        'http://192.168.1.4:8080/api/childcategory/' + idSelected,
        {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.status == 200) {
        setData_child(data.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.wrap} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
              <Text style={styles.heading}>
                An English learning app to improve your English vocabulary
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.listCategoryItem}>
            {data.map(renderCategoryItem)}
          </View>

          <View style={styles.listChildCategory}>
            <Text style={styles.listChildCategoryText}>
              Some categories for you
            </Text>

            <View style={styles.listCategory}>
              <FlatList
                data={data_child}
                // extraData={data_child}
                // keyExtractor ={(item)=> item.id}
                renderItem={renderChildCategoryItem}
              />
              
              {loading && (
                <View style={styles.loading}>
                  <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#F1CB7A" />
                </View>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

**This is my ChildCategoryItem.js`**

```
const ChildCategoryItem = ({data_child}, props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.container}
      // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quiz',{id: item.id}) }
      // onPress={() => navigation.push('Quiz',item)}
    >
      <Button
        title="Start"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Quiz', {id: item.id})}
      />
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: data_child.Image}} style={styles.image} />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{data_child.id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.description}>{data_child.Description}</Text>
      <View style={styles.smileList}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/images/smile.png')}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
        <Text style={styles.smile}>{data_child.smile || 0}%</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

**This is my Quiz.js**

```
    export default class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      questions: [],
      current: 0,
      correctScore: 5,
      totalScore: 50,
      data: {
        score: 0,
        correctAnswers: 0
      },
      completed: false
    };
  }

  
  fetchQuestions = async () => {
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    await this.setState({ loading: true });
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://192.168.1.4:8080/api/question/`, + params.id,
      // + params,
      {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
    );
    const questions = await response.json();

    const { data } = questions;

    data.forEach(item => {
      item.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    });

    await this.setState({ questions: data, loading: false });
  };
```

Comment: How’s your navigator setup? Also functional component have one args which is props but yours child category have 2 args which seems wrong. Also there is no `this` in functional component.

Comment: I try to pass the id of the child_category  to the url of the question. You can see in the code i use param.id. But I really stuck in this case. I just post everthing related to child_category

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried console logging the on press to see if its even getting called? I believe this is probably a styling/method issue as you're trying to wrap the whole component in a touchable opacity. Try changing the touchable opacity to a view instead and click the button to navigate to the screen.

If that doesn't work, your navigation function probably isn't getting passed down through props. Also ensure you imported TouchableOpacity from react-native and not react-native-gesture-handler.

EDIT: It seems your button uses "props" but your wrapper uses "this.props" you should be using "props" as it is being passed down through a functional component and not a class based one.

Comment: i tried to console logging the onpres and it's still working. I also change from Touchable Opacity to View but i can't to navigate to the quiz screen. 'this' in onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quiz', {id: item.id})} is undefined. I don't know why

Comment: See my edited answer, "this" is undefined because you're passing it down through props.

Comment: so how can i fix this? Do you have any solution?

Comment: Remove "this" and use "props.navigation.navigate" instead

Comment: no it's just a comment. i only use props.navigation.navigate in the button. it's still not working. Now I have this error (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation')).

Comment: You are not passing down your navigator to your child category item you are only passing down "data_child={item}". There is no way for your navigation prop to get there as you are not passing it down.  In "Home.js" get the navigation prop and pass it down through child category item

Comment: So what I shoud write in Home.js? Const Home({navigation}) or i shoud write something under data_child = ({item}) in renderChildCategortItem. Sorry for many question. I’m a newbie in React Native

Comment: I can navigate to the Quiz screen. But how can I pass the id of child_category to Quiz.js to  display the all question by child_category id correctly? I try to use params + id but it's not working